# ASUS EAH5450 Graphics Card (ATI Radeon HD5450 - 1 GB DDR3) on Windows 2003? Anybody got it to work?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, windows-server-2003

I've just bought an ASUS EAH5450 Graphics Card (ATI Radeon HD5450, 1 GB DDR3) for my main system, but I haven't been able to make it work under Windows 2003 (my OS in that system).

When I plugged the card, I got a couple of "installing drivers" prompt for things such as "ATI High Definition Audio Device" that got themselves sorted out of the Internet, and then a "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter".

The CD that came with the card installs something called "ATI Catalyst Install Manager" and .net 2.0, but no drivers. I've downloaded the latest (WinXP 32bits) drivers from ATI, and the experience is the same: I don't get any drivers installed.

My Motherboard is an ASUS A8N-SLI with nVidia nForce 4 chipset (for an Athlon 64X2, somewhat old), but my previous card was an ATi Radeon X700, so it's been working with ATI cards before.

On POST, during boot I see a "Display Card" Device (Vendor ID 1002-68F9-0300) and a "Multimedia Device" (1002-AA68-0403), and when viewing the properties of the "Standard VGA", they match the device ID.

Any hints? I'd really hate having to get rid of the card, and I'm sure it's not that strange what I'm trying to do...

Comment: You have to get rid of the really outdate OS of yours. Install XP / Vista / Win 7,  anything supported. :)

Comment: @Shiki, Windows 2003 is still in Mainstream Support for a few more months. Extended Support ends in 2015.

Comment: Yes it is supported but not by ATI as far as I know.

Comment: @Shiki - The good thing about server-level OS for workstation is that it's been rock solid for 4+ years, and is the simplest way to go if you want to run services off your main system, as I do.

I know I'll likely have to migrate off it, soon, but I'd rather do on my time (and I hope I'll find a way to use W2K8 as workstation, as I did for w2k3: http://www.msfn.org/win2k3/hardwareacc.htm)

Comment: Well... for me, XP served about 6-7 years, and its still works, no problem, no slowness at all. Yes I am also running services. To be honest I only see point in running the server edition where you want multiple users to access the services like RDP, but that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've been able to install the ATI drivers. I got them from the ATI site, and launched the .exe that decompressed on C:\ATI\. The default install behaves as the included drivers: it launches the "ATI Catalyst Install Manager" that lets you update the install manager itself, and install .NET 2.0.

Going to device manager, selecting the VGA Graphics card, and choosing the "update driver" option, and pointing it to the "WXP" subdir that had drivers (C:\ATI\\Packages\Drivers\WXP), it recognizes the card and install as Radeon HD 5450. dxdiag show Graphics accel working (I had it enabled long time ago, to use my 2k3 as workstation - see http://www.msfn.org/win2k3/hardwareacc.htm), and Call Of Duty 4 runs fine (much better than it did; on boot the game told me the hardware had changed and suggested me to up the resolution).

Now if I can I'll try install the Catalyst Control Center, but that's 2nd priority.

Thanks to all that answered.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Windows server 2003 is not on the list of operating systems in the release notes for the ATI driver of this card.

I would therefore first try Windows Update, to see if it can suggest an optional driver update for the video card.

Second, download the latest [driver from ATI](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_catalyst.aspx?p=xp/radeonx-xp) for XP, which dates more or less from the same period. There's a new driver which dates from a couple of weeks ago.

If this doesn't work, you may have to make a choice between your operating system and your graphic card.

My comment is that the Server family of Windows is not targeted at high-level graphical usage. In fact, it comes without even Windows Media Player, which does take some effort to install by brute force.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's true that it's not a supported OS, but I've always been able to use it before and it's galling.

As for not using W2K3 for "high end graphical usage", I'd have to disagree with you: most of the pros I know that do CAD/CAM/3D design on Windows use 2K3 - Win7 is starting to show promise now :)

Comment: @JJarava: Using graphics in 2K3 is possible, but requires some acrobatics. Instead of converting a server OS to desktop, why not use a desktop version to start with?

Answer (score 1):

After the 6/2012 driver update, I found my driver that seems to work in this folder:

```
C:\AMD\Support\12-6_xp32_dd_ccc\Packages\Drivers\WDM\HDMI\XP
```